Named orbifolds
The spindle and the pillowcase are 2-dimensional orbifolds (the latter being flat everywhere, except at the singular points of course). Are there any named higher-dimensional orbifolds? In particular, are there any which are not everywhere flat?

This question is rather vague. For instance, would your question be answered by a classification scheme which lists all of the orbifolds of particular types, together with descriptions of invariants that distinguish all of the members of those lists? Such schemes exist for 3-dimensional spherical orbifolds, and for 3-dimensional Euclidean orbifolds, for example. But if you want to know whether they all have names like John or Mary or the Orthochronic Pentahydrodynamic Orbifold, then your question becomes rather subjective.

What do you mean by "everywhere flat"? This is not a standard terminology. Do you mean an orbifild admitting  a Euclidean metric? Or an orbifold which is homeomorphic to a manifold as a topological space?
